# Two Magento Frontend eShops on the same store (selling the same products)?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, inventory

I have two magento 1.9 e-shops right now. They sell the same products but have separate magento installations. Now I got the request to somehow merge them into one.

The end result should look like this.

- The customer can reach each website on their own domain.
- But when they buy things it will be from the same store (as in the same products).
- So one sell on website1 will also register as one sell on website2.

Right now I think I should go about it like this. One "Website" in magento, one "Store", and two "Store Views". Would this be working? I would probably need to copy the theme over and then work in the backend by changing the Store View. Will this be working? Or am I totally off here.

If some of you had to deal with this and could lend me some help that would be awesome!

Thanks!